# What headers are allowed in functions?

Tags: php, http-headers

What kind of headers are allowed  to be set from inside a function?
It is OK if I set MIME type for an image from inside a function?

Example:

```
function createImage($parameters) {
    /**
     * Here process parameters
     */
    // Set header
    header ('Content-Type: image/png');
    // create the image an destroy it
}
```

Are there any advantages or disadvantages if setting the header from inside a function? What are the best practices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any technical restriction besides the usual "headers already sent" stuff, except most people won't expect a function to modify response headers unless it's specifically designed and documented to do that.

The best practice is not to do it within a function unless it's clear that headers are being modified, and that it's not just happening on accident as a side effect.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you do not send any data to the browser, you're free to include any header you want. Though it wouldn't make a difference for the browser to include custom headers like `X-What: Ever`.

To avoid errors in case you've accidentally outputted data before, use something like:

```
if (!headers_sent()) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
}
```

The advantage of using this method is that you do not have to repeat the `header(..)` every time you create an image to be send to the browser.

But, judging from the comment below ("create the image an destroy it"), it doesn't sound like you want to display an image to the browser (display in the meaning of "send a raw image", not "show a HTML page with an image on it"). In that case, do not send the `header` as it may confuse the browser.

Comment: if (!headers_sent()) header('Content-Type: image/png'); - hmm, i really need to set the header if i don't then i`m getting a bunch of odd text from the image generation so the information needs to be set in the right context to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

> What kind of headers are allowed to be set from inside a function?

Any.

You can't set headers after you have sent content, but it doesn't matter if you use a function or not.

> Are there any advantages or disadvantages if setting the header from inside a function?

The same as for using functions for anything else.